# do radial limits imply non-tangential limits

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on the closed unit disk, except possibly at the boundary point $z=1$, and is holomorphic inside the disk. If $\lim_{z\rightarrow1}f(z)$ exists inside a neighborhood of a line segment $(1-\varepsilon,1)$, and so in particular the radial limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}f(x)$ exists, can anything be said about the non-tangential limits?

In particular, for a given Stolz angle $\frac{|1-z|}{1-|z|}\le M$, does $\lim_{z\rightarrow1}f(z)$ exist? Is not, can we bound $|f(z)|$ in this region (with the bound allowed to depend on $M$)?

I know there are classical results when $f$ is a bounded function, but can anything be said without that assumption? My instinct is not.

Comment: You need $f$ to be in some Hardy (or Nevanlinna) space, so you need some control on growth at the boundary; inverses of singular inner functions give counterexamples

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f_k(z) = \exp(-1/(1-z)^k)$ for positive integers $k$.  If $z = 1-r e^{i\theta}$, 
$f_k(z) = \exp(- \exp(ik\theta)/r^k)$ so $|f_k(z)| = \exp(-\cos(k\theta)/r^k)$.
Thus $|f_k(z)| \to 0$ as $r \to 0+$ iff $\cos(k\theta) > 0$, while $|f_k(z)| \to \infty$ if $\cos(k\theta) < 0$.  For any given angle $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, we can choose $k$ so $\cos(k\theta) < 0$ and $|f_k(z)| \to \infty$ as you approach $1$ at angle $\theta$.